# Getting product quantity before and after saving a product in magento

Tags: magento

I have catch an event `catalog_product_save_commit_after` and written an observer for it to get product stock.

In `config.xml` I have written the code below

```
<events>
     <catalog_product_save_commit_after>
       <observers>
         <Arkix_Logs_observer>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>Arkix_Logs_Model_Observer</class>
           <method>get_update_inventory</method>
         </Arkix_Logs_observer>
       </observers>
     </catalog_product_save_commit_after>     
   </events>
```

In `Observer.php` I have written:

```
 public function get_update_inventory( $observer){

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    $origStockData = $product->getOrigData('stock_item')->getOrigData();//to get original stock
    echo '<pre>';print_r($origStockData);
    $stockData = $product->getStockItem()->getData();//to get new stock

   echo "product name id   ".$product->getId();

  die('haha');
}
```

But error is coming Call to a member function `getOrigData()` on non object in observer.php

Comment: I think you need to instantiate the model Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item') before using the getOridData() function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to instantiate the model `Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')` before using the `getOridData()` function. So 
try,

```
public function get_update_inventory( $observer){

$productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();

$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($productId); 
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

print_r($stocklevel);

}
```

comment here if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that comes across this, there are 2 things wrong here:

1. ```
   ...
    <catalog_product_save_commit_after>
      ...
    </catalog_product_save_commit_after>
   ```

   The event that you should be using is

   ```
   ...
    <catalog_product_save_after>
      ...
    </catalog_product_save_after>
   ```

   Since the method `getOridData()` is only available before the transaction is commited.
2. The method to get the observer product is `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();` , not `$observer->getEvent()->getItem();`

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try following code instead of using getOrigData()

`$product->getStockItem()->getQty()`;

Comment: I think you have not understood my requirement.I want to get product quantity before and after update of product inventory